# In Python 3.5, when dividing an even number, why divide and floor divide gives different answer

Tags: python, division

I am trying to divide a very large even number `13144131834269512219260941993714669605006625743172006030529504645527800951523697620149903055663251854220067020503783524785523675819158836547734770656069476`
I used both division and floor division, but it provides me two different answers which I think should be the same.
So I got

```
int(x/2) = 6572065917134756165333387211683112531415896759844144557192219233347999705289073358407747856661759761476763448808302430806962124152349175018830474952835072
int(x//2) = 6572065917134756109630470996857334802503312871586003015264752322763900475761848810074951527831625927110033510251891762392761837909579418273867385328034738
```

is anyone could tell me what results in the differences?
Thanks

Comment: `int()` on `//` is redundant. `/` produces a *float*, and floating point numbers have limits. You exceeded them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/` true division always produces a floating point result, and you can't accurately model your number with floats:

```
>>> huge = 13144131834269512219260941993714669605006625743172006030529504645527800951523697620149903055663251854220067020503783524785523675819158836547734770656069476
>>> huge / 2
6.572065917134756e+153
>>> type(huge / 2)
<class 'float'>
```

That's 6 times 10^153, but `float` can only carry 53 binary digits of precision in the mantissa:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.float_info.mant_dig
53
```

Floating point uses *binary fractions* to model the decimal portion, which means that for the majority of possible decimal values, this is only an approximation anyway.

Converting that value to `int()` is not going to bring back the precision that was lost.

`//` floor division on the other hand, produces an integer for integer inputs, and integers have arbitrary precision, so nothing is lost:

```
>>> type(huge // 2)
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: While you can definitely get the mantissa from `sys.float_info.mant_dig` is it correct to say that it is 53 on all platforms?

Comment: @LabrysKnossos: it believe it will be 53 on all modern platforms Python runs on, yes.